# Node module-alias Error: Cannot find module '@src/utils/constants'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ask-cli

I'm running mocha tests and I recently upgraded to the newest version of the ask-cli.  I ran the tests again and I'm now receiving this module error.  I've npm installed src and utils to no avail.  From what I've read it's possible module-alias does not support @src paths.

I'm calling this command:

```
$ ask api simulate-skill -l en-US -t "start my day" -s amzn1.ask.skill.XXXXXXXX-4156-4ca0-b14e-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Update: this seems to be an issue with the ask-cli which uses

`const CONSTANTS = require('@src/utils/constants');`
The @src should find the source of the node package but this @src is not used in any other packages I could find. All other packages seem to use ../../ so that's likely while module-alias does not find anything bc it doesn't know how to route this new syntax

Does anyone know of this new @src syntax and if there is a npm module for helping route it?

Which worked for ask-cli 1.1.6 but I upgraded to 1.7.2 for new functionality.

```
Error: Cannot find module '@src/utils/constants'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/calebgates/WebstormProjects/AutomatedUtteranceTesting/node_modules/module-alias/index.js:49:29)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/calebgates/WebstormProjects/AutomatedUtteranceTesting/node_modules/ask-cli/lib/commands/init/index.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Module.replacementCompile (/Users/calebgates/WebstormProjects/AutomatedUtteranceTesting/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:58:13)
    at module.exports (/Users/calebgates/WebstormProjects/AutomatedUtteranceTesting/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/default-require-extensions/js.js:8:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/calebgates/WebstormProjects/AutomatedUtteranceTesting/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:62:4)
module.js:549
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by including the `ask-sdk` in my local project's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This is acknowledged [bug](https://github.com/alexa/ask-cli/issues/42) when `ask-cli` is installed locally. There are two work-arounds pointed out in the [bug](https://github.com/alexa/ask-cli/issues/42) report.

Either install `ask-cli` globally:

```
   $ npm install -g ask-cli
```

Or install the `module-alias` package:

```
   $ npm install module-alias
```

and configure it to look for `@src` in the `ask-cli/lib` folder by adding the following to your package.json file:

```
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@src": "./node_modules/ask-cli/lib",
    "@root": "./node_modules/ask-cli",
    "@test": "./node_modules/ask-cli/test"
  }
```